# Execute command but singe and double quotations already used

Tags: command-line

I have two commands here. The first command works in my php.ini but the second one will not. The only difference between the commands is "XAMPPEmails" VS "XAMPP Emails" with a space. I want to have the emails be created in my Documents/XAMPP Emails folder and my only issue is that I already have used the singe quotes and double quotes. How would I make this work with both quotation being used?

```
sendmail_path = "cat > /home/USERNAME/Documents/XAMPPEmails/`date '+%Y-%m-%d - %H-%M-%S'`.eml" 


sendmail_path = "cat > /home/USERNAME/Documents/XAMPP Emails/`date '+%Y-%m-%d - %H-%M-%S'`.eml"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the space.

```
 sendmail_path = "cat > /home/USERNAME/Documents/XAMPP\ Emails/`date '+%Y-%m-%d - %H-%M-%S'`.eml"
```